# ValueError at /accounts/profile/edit/,,,,, Field 'id' expected a number but got 'edit'

Tags: python, django

```py
# models.py


from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class UserprofileCity(models.manager):
     def get_queryset(self):
         return super(UserprofileCity,self).get_queryset().filter(city='surat')


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # you an add extra fields as per requirements after

    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')

    description = models.CharField(max_length= 500,default='')

    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(default='+91',max_length=13,help_text='enter mobile number with country code')

    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):

    if kwargs['created']:

        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

```
# views.py:


from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import RegistrationForm,EditProfileForm,ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash


def register(request):

    if request.method =='POST':

        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return redirect(reverse('accounts:login'))


    else:

        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form':form}

        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)


def profile_view(request,pk=None):

    if pk:

        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    else:

        user = request.user

    args = {'user':user}

    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)


def profile_edit(request):

    if request.method =='POST':

        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)

        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.Post,request.FILES,instance=request.user.userprofile)


        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user_form = form.save()

            custom_form = profile_form.save(False)

            custom_form.user = user_form

            custom_form.save()

            return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile_view'))

    else:

        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)

        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)


        args = {

            'form':form, 'profile_form':profile_form

        }

        return render(request,'accounts/profile_edit.html',args)


def password_change(request):

    if request.method=='POST':

        form = PasswordChangeForm(data = request.POST,user=request.user)


        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(request,form.user)

            return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile_view'))

        else:

            return redirect(reverse('accounts:change_password'))

    else:

        form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user)

        args = {'form':form}

        return render(request,'accounts/password_change.html',args)
```

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView,
    LogoutView,
    PasswordResetView,
    PasswordResetDoneView,
    PasswordResetCompleteView,
    PasswordResetConfirmView,
)

app_name = 'accounts'


urlpatterns = [

    ###

    #user

    ###

    path('login/',LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'accounts/login.html'),name='login'),

    path('logout/',LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'),name = 'logout'),

    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),


    ###

    #profile

    ###


    path('profile/',views.profile_view,name='profile_view'),

    path('profile/<pk>/',views.profile_view,name='other_profile_view'),

    path('profile/edit/',views.profile_edit,name='profile_edit'),


    ###

    #change_password

    ###


    path('change-password/',views.password_change,name='password_change'),


    ###

    # reset password

    ###


    path('reset-password/',PasswordResetView.as_view(

        template_name = 'accounts/password_reset.html',

        email_template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_email.html',

        subject_template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_subject.txt',

        success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done'),

         ),name='password_reset'),


    path('password_reset/done/',PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(

        template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_done.html',

    ),name = 'password_reset_done'),


    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(

        success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete'),

        template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_confirm.html',


    ),name='password_reset_confirm'),


    path('reset/done/',PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(

        template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_complete.html',


    ),name='password_reset_complete'),
```

```
# profile.html


{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}

Profile

{% endblock %}



{% block body %}



<div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="col-md-8">

        <h1>{{user}} Profile</h1>

        <hr>

        <p> Username : {{user}} </p>

        <p> First Name : {{user.first_name}} </p>

        <p> Last Name : {{user.last_name}} </p>

        <p> Age : {{ user.userprofile.age }} </p>

        <p> Email : {{ user.email}} </p>

        <p> Description : {{ user.userprofile.description }} </p>

        <p> Phone : {{ user.userprofile.phone_number }}</p>

        <p> city : {{ user.userprofile.city }} </p>

        <p> Website : {{ user.userprofile.website }} </p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        {% if user.userprofile.image %}

        <img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" width="400"><br>



        {% endif %}

        <br>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'accounts:profile_edit' %}">Edit Profile</a>



        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'accounts:password_change' %}">Change Password</a>



        </div>

    </div>

</div>



{% endblock %}
```

When I run with these files, I get this error:

```
traceback:
The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'edit') was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Kraj\Desktop\practice\demo4\post\accounts\views.py", line 25, in profile_view
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 74, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(


Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/profile/edit/

Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'edit'.
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJg3z.png)

Comment: There is a typo, POST method should be in caps in the edit profile function.

Comment: You've provided way too much information. If you want more help you're going to need to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm guessing the issue is that `'profile/<pk>/'` matches before `profile/edit/` so it's passing `pk = 'edit'` to `profile_view`.

Comment: sorry for the question with too much information. I am not used to posting questions here so I didn't know about it. by d way, I did make changes based on your suggestion, and its work good, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, POST method should be in caps in the edit profile function. Fixing it over here.

def profile_edit(request):

```
if request.method =='POST':

    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)

    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.userprofile)


    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

        user_form = form.save()

        custom_form = profile_form.save(False)

        custom_form.user = user_form

        custom_form.save()

        return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile_view'))

else:

    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)


    args = {

        'form':form, 'profile_form':profile_form

    }

    return render(request,'accounts/profile_edit.html',args)
```